# Javascript Event For When CascadingDropdown Finishes Populating?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, act

I have a State DDL and a Country DDL. I have CascadingDropdown controls for each of those DDLs.

When the user selects an entry from the Country DDL, the State dropdown gets populated with the results of a service method call.

I want to disable a submit button while the State dropdown is populating. Is there a way to capture when the State DDL finishes populating so that I can do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CascadingDropdown provides no such JavaScript event as far as I have seen.

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling your service method?  Both the Microsoft AJAX library and jQuery offer a callback method when you execute an AJAX call.  In your javascript function that calls the service, disable the button.  Provide a callback to the AJAX call's 'onSuccess' (or whatever it is called) that turns it back on.

[Quick article on Microsoft AJAX PageMethods javascript class.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattgi/archive/2006/11/15/accessing-session-data-from-javascript.aspx)

[jQuery ajax() method.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: The CascadingDropdown calls the service method. My code doesn't directly call the service method. My question was essentially whether the CascadingDropdown fires an event that  I can use to handle when the CascadingDropdown has finished populating a child menu. Though I'm able to specify a service method on the CascadingDropdown for it to call, I've not seen a way to specify a callback.